# Handling keyboard input on a dialog - Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I am programming an application that is non-modal dialog based. I am using the Visual Studio resource editor to build the dialog and create the application. Everything is going great so far. However, I have reached a brick wall when it comes to handling keyboard input. My research has shown that windows captures keyboard input before it reaches the dialog callback procedure to implement the ability to move the focus using the keyboard.

I created a bare bones dialog to test this and, when I have a dialog without any controls on it, everything works as I would expect it to. When I add a control, it stops working.

Here is the code from the bare bones project:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "resource.h"

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM  lParam);
HWND dlghandle;
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE h0, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
HWND hDlg;
MSG msg;
BOOL ret;


hDlg = CreateDialogParam(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, DialogProc, 0);
ShowWindow(hDlg, nCmdShow);
dlghandle = hDlg;
while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0) {
    if (ret == -1)
        return -1;
    if (!IsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
return 0;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 {
    switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Test", L"Test", MB_OK);
    break;
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hDlg);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
    break;
}
return 0;
}
```

What options do I have?

Comment: Keyboard input goes to the window with focus; when you add a control that can have focus on it, that control will have focus. What kind of key press do you want to handle?

Comment: I just need to handle a simple input from one of the alphanumeric keys, such as the Q or S key. What is going to happen is, my app will write to a file when the button is pressed. I have tried using SetFocus(dialoghandle) with dialoghandle being the handle to the dialog. Even though the call succeeds, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: The first place keyboard input appears is your message loop, so just check for the keypress you're looking for before passing it off to `IsDialogMessage`/`TranslateMessage`/`DispatchMessage`.

Comment: Jonathan Potter - Thanks! That worked perfectly, Such as simple solution. If you rewrite as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place keyboard input appears is your message loop, so just check for the keypress you're looking for before passing it off to `IsDialogMessage()` / `TranslateMessage()` / `DispatchMessage()`. For example:

```
while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0) {
    if (ret == -1)
        return -1;

    if (msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN && msg.wParam == 'Q')
    {
        // trap and handle the Q key no matter which control has focus
    }
    else
    if (!IsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

If you wanted you could even wrap this in a function to make it neater, e.g.:

```
#define MYMSG_DOSOMETHING   (WM_APP + 1)

BOOL MyIsDialogMessage(HWND hDlg, MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->wParam == 'Q')
    {
        PostMessage(hDlg, MYMSG_DOSOMETHING, 0, 0);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return IsDialogMessage(hDlg, pMsg);
}


// then your message loop would be:

while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0) {
    if (ret == -1)
        return -1;

    if (!MyIsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use **SetWindowsHook** to create low level keyboard proc.
**NOTE** this looks a bit complex and advanced  but it works great with Dialogs without doing any extra effort to message loop.

```
HHOOK g_hLowLevelKeyHook;

//windows Main.
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    g_hLowLevelKeyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

........
....... 
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pkbhs = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION && wParam == WM_KEYUP)
    {
        if (pkbhs->vkCode == VK_F1)
            MessageBoxA(NULL"F1 Pressed","INFO",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hLowLevelKeyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```