# How do I make a prompt that closes when a letter is clicked?

Tags: python-3.x, winapi

So I'm new to programming and all, and tried doing it but the prompt somehow ends the loop. Is there any  simple alternative for this?

```
import time
import win32api

c = 1
x = 1
        
while x == 1:
        if c==1:
                a=win32api.MessageBox(0, "*Question here*?(y/n)", "Prompt")
                c=c+1
                
        y = win32api.GetKeyState(0x59)
        n = win32api.GetKeyState(0x4E)
        if y<0 and n>=0:
                x=x+1
                print("y")
                a.close()
        elif y>=0 and n<0:
                x=x+1
                print("n")
                a.close()

        time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? This code isn't going to be useful for anything. Perhaps if we know what you want to do we can steer you in the right direction.

Comment: `MessageBox` is a blocking function. [There is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783817/handling-keyboard-input-on-a-dialog-windows). Because the system only provides a special keyboard interface for dialog boxes that carries out special processing for several keys, We redirect messages which are in the thread queue is a solution.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].